# How To start serial port service on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, spp

I am trying to make a simple android application that connects to a PC via Blue-tooth and continually monitors characters sent to it from the PC. But it has to use the serial port profile(SPP) because the PC has to send the characters via virtual Blue-tooth com ports(I am actually using mat-lab to send the characters via the com port). The problem is when i start to configure incoming virtual serial port for the blue-tooth(in the blue-tooth settings), it says my android device doesn't have serial port service running. How could i start that service on my phone or is there any application that runs in the background and starts the service for me ... please help!!

Answer (score 1):

With a terminal application, you can do this:

```
sdptool add --channel=16 SP
```

Where 16 is replaceable by your channel number.